# Find new files being created anywhere on filesystem

Tags: unix, find

Is there a Unix command I can run that will print the names of new files being created anywhere on the file system? Or list any file in descending order of date created/date modified?

Comment: Sure, I tried googling and searching SO. Nothing relevant came up. I also considered running a recursive find sorted by date modified on my filesystem, but this turned out to be too slow.

Comment: You said it "turned out to be too slow".  Show us what you did and then we can go from there.

Comment: `time find / -Bmin 20 2>/dev/null` ran in about 4 minutes on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Linux feature named inotify that may be useful, check it out for example here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) or [`inotifywatch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch) utilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you run an OS supporting Dtrace:

```
syscall::creat*:entry { printf("%Y %d %s %s", walltimestamp, uid, execname, copyinstr(arg0)); }
```